# Coordinate storage in cvmat header

Tags: opencv

How can i use `CvRect cvBoundingRect(CvArr* points, int update=0 )` with a `cvmat` header?

```
CvRect _square;

CvMat* data=cvCreateMatHeader(2,4,CV_8S); // CvArr* type storage for 4 pair of coordinates
```

How can I fill with coordinates?

```
(30,30)
(200,50)
(100,140)
(275,120)    

_square=cvBoundingRect(data);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't.

a [boundingRect](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#boundingrect) is used with a vector of Points, not with a Mat of any kind.

```
vector<Point> points;
points.push_back(Point(30,30));
points.push_back(Point(200,50));
points.push_back(Point(100,140));
points.push_back(Point(275,120));  

Rect bounds = boundingRect(points);

cerr << bounds << endl;
```

---

```
[246 x 111 from (30, 30)]
```

---

also, please stay away from opencv's deprecated c-api, if you see code containing IplImages, CvArr or similar, - its all far too old to be used.

Comment: no, you do not even have any choice there. rather you *must not* use it.

Comment: please do so, opencv changed to a c++ api in 2010 already. any remaining c-api calls are emulated via c++, and are only there for backwards compatibility.